# SQL Server Table-valued function lock question

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

I have a Table-valued function

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fn_Test
()
RETURNS 
@t TABLE 
(
    ID INT
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @t(ID) select ID from dbo.Table;    
    RETURN 
END
GO
```

My question is, if I use this function in a select statement joined to another table for example, will the main query aqcuire shared read locks on dbo.Table? or will it acquire the lock INDEPENDENTLY from the main query to fill the table variable?

thanks,

Comment: Here's an idea, try it and see :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least at read committed in SQL Server 2019 the locks are released as soon as the table variable is populated.

I could see this in Profiler (with green being the object id of the table and yellow the object id of the function)

[image]

I wasn't 100% sure that I hadn't missed anything so I tried the following setup...

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T1(ID int primary key)

CREATE TABLE dbo.T2(ID int primary key)

INSERT  dbo.T1 VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)

INSERT  dbo.T2 VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)

GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_Test()
RETURNS @t TABLE ( ID INT)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @t(ID) select ID from dbo.T1;    
    RETURN 
END
GO
```

and I was able to start off the following query (returns 1,953,125 rows and takes at least 10 seconds for me)

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.T2 a
CROSS JOIN dbo.T2 b
CROSS JOIN dbo.T2 c
CROSS JOIN dbo.T2 d
CROSS JOIN dbo.T2 e
CROSS JOIN dbo.T2 f
CROSS JOIN dbo.T2 g
CROSS JOIN dbo.T2 h
CROSS JOIN dbo.T2 i
JOIN dbo.fn_Test() fn ON fn.ID = a.ID
```

Then immediately go to another window and run

```
drop table dbo.T1
```

which succeeded without being blocked and with results still streaming in the other connection

Comment: The new interleaved execution might affect this

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment...

Just saying you can simplify your function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION  pyro.fn_Test ()
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

   Select ID from dbo.Table

)
```

Comment: Nitpic, but i think you cannot use ALTER on a function to change it to inline from non-inline version

Comment: Maybe worth noting that for an online table valued function, it's evaluated as part of the main query plan.

Comment: @DaleK - I think you have a small typo ("online" vs "inline").